# Are there any downside of creating LVM using raided device?

Tags: raid, lvm

I want to use the performance of RAID-0 and flexibility of LVM for managing storage.

I have created RAID-0 using two disk of equal size and then created a PV and 
included in VG. Then I have created LV of desired size.

I understand that if any device in RAID array fails the complete array will also fail.
I am planning to use this stack in my production, so are there any other downside of using RAID-0 with LVM ?

Comment: Do you need another? If you really need the performance, why not RAID-10?

Comment: RAID-10 will mirror the data apart from providing performance and in my environment only performance is required. The data can be generated any time so mirroring is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Outside of the obligatory 'RAID-0 is unsafe' warnings using LVM for it's flexibility is still a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You're using RAID-0. Adding LVM on top of it won't change anything when one of the disks fails. Using it for flexibility is a good idea.

Just remember to put RAID0 volumes in different volume group than the rest of LVM volumes (if you have any) as LVM group becomes unavailable and requires manual assembly when any of the member disks becomes unavailable.